# How to do this in Clickonce?

Tags: clickonce

As I don't have a webserver, I have got to host my application off Dropbox. I would like to be able to roll out updates, however I'm not sure of the link that Dropbox will give me. Is there any way to change the link AFTER I've published the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

Publish it, and for the URL field put `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/(user ID HERE)/(The Folder You Want To Put It In)/`. Then, when it finishes publishing, copy the files over to Dropbox. That will map to a folder with the name `(The Folder You Want To Put It In)` in your Dropbox public folder.